# Can someone please explain what's going on with cv qualifiers in gcc's implementation of _Bind::call_x()

Tags: c++

So I have 2 questions wrt this whole bind implementation -

1. Consider this piece of code from class _Bind's member function -

```
template<typename _Result, typename... _Args, std::size_t... _Indexes>
    _Result
    __call_v(tuple<_Args...>&& __args,
         _Index_tuple<_Indexes...>) volatile
    {
      return std::__invoke(_M_f,
          _Mu<_Bound_args>()(__volget<_Indexes>(_M_bound_args), __args)...
          );
    }
```

If `_M_bound_args` is a member of the class, and function is volatile qualified, wouldn't `M_bound_args`, also be implicitly volatile type, as this method will be invoked from a volatile `_Bind` object, then what's the need of `__volget` function? Same for `const volatile` qualified version as well.

2. In definition of `_Mu::operator`, `std::get<_Indexes>(std::move(__tuple))...` is used. Even though `get<>` may not actually move the entire tuple, but isn't that conceptually incorrect, to move the tuple, which holds all the arguments passed to bind to be used for other arguments as well? Snippet

```
template<typename _Arg>
    class _Mu<_Arg, false, true>
    {
    public:
      template<typename _Tuple>
    _GLIBCXX20_CONSTEXPR
    _Safe_tuple_element_t<(is_placeholder<_Arg>::value - 1), _Tuple>&&
    operator()(const volatile _Arg&, _Tuple& __tuple) const volatile
    {
      return
        ::std::get<(is_placeholder<_Arg>::value - 1)>(std::move(__tuple));
    }
    };
```

I am not able to make sense of this, I do not see such constructs in clang's implementation though.

So, an explanation would be quite helpful.